# Is the 'appropriate' constructible hierarchy a model of ZFC?

Tags: set-theory, first-order-logic

Working in with the constructible hierarchy, let's define $Birth$ and $Rank$ of sets as:

$Birth(x)=\alpha \iff min \ \alpha: x \in L_{\alpha+1}$

$Rank(x)=\alpha \iff min \ \alpha : x  \subseteq L_\alpha  $

Let's call sets $appropriate$, if and only if their birth is their rank, for example $\omega$.

Now if we build a new hierarchy $L'$ that requires sets to be not just constructible from below, but also appropriate. Lets denote the stages of that hierarchy by $L'_\alpha$, so each successor stage $L'_{\alpha+1}$ is the set of all appropriate constructible subsets of the prior stage $L'_\alpha$. Of course $L'$ is the union of all appropriate constructible successor and limit stages.

Question 1: Is $L'$ is an inner model of ZFC?

Question 2: is $L'_\omega = L_\omega $?

Comment: Aren't birth and rank always the same?

Comment: @Wojowu No, e.g. all constructible reals are subsets of $L_{\omega}$ but many are not elements of $L_{\omega+1}$

Comment: Wouldn't $L'$ be an inner model strictly smaller than $L$? (This can't exist by minimality of $L$.)

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen Ah, yes, of course. Subsets of $L_\omega$ needn't be definable so needn't lie in $L_{\omega+1}$. Rookie mistake!

Comment: @Wojowu Yes, exactly. To see that this always happens, note $L_{\omega+1}$ is countable in $L$ whereas $P(\omega)\cap L$ is uncountable in $L$. (They might both be countable in real life.)

Comment: @Wojowu not only that! You can have subsets of $L_\omega$ that are not definable using parameters in $L_\omega$, but they can still be "definable" but from parameters belonging to stages higher than $\omega$, for example the diagonal on the bijection between $L_\omega$ and $L_{\omega+1}$ that bijection can be definable but its birth would be at two stages higher than $L_{\omega+1}$ and the diagonal using it as a parameter would have its birth at 3 stages higher than $L_{\omega+1}$, while the rank of that diagonal is obviously at $L_\omega$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot possibly expect to have $L'$ as a model of $\sf ZF$, since it is clearly smaller than $L$.

To see why, note that your requirement shows that $\mathcal P(\omega)^{L'}\subseteq L_{\omega+1}$. But this set is countable in $L$, and so certainly not the power set of $\omega$ itself.

Comment: is $\mathcal P(\omega)^{L'}$ provably countable in $L'$? There might be a proof that it is not countable in $L'$? is there something against that?

Comment: It is provable in $\sf ZF$ that $L_{\alpha+1}$ has the same cardinality as $L_\alpha$.

Comment: Then which of the known theories $L'$ is a model of? It contains all ordinals of $ZFC$, but its stages are thinner than those of ZFC?

Comment: I don't know. But not even $\Delta_0$-separation.

Comment: is it weaker than Kripke-Platek set theory?

Comment: @Zuhair KP has $\Delta_0$ separation. ($\Delta_1$ separation in fact.)

Comment: @Yes, that's what made me think this is much weaker than KP. Perhaps it would be equivalent to some predicative kind of set theory. Not sure. However it has a very tall hierarchy, as tall as ZFC! And yet extremely thin stages?

Comment: @Zuhair: So does the class of ordinals.

Comment: @AsafKaragila: but we are iterating appropriate constructibility $\alpha$ many time for each ordinal $\alpha$ in $L$? so $L'$ must be at least as high as $L$. No?

Comment: @Zuhair: My point is that just because something is a proper class doesn't mean that it has some strength or whatever.

Comment: @AsafKaragila, But its the same proper class. The class $ORD$ of $L$ is exactly the same class $ORD$ of $L'$, so they must have the same height or whatever, that's a consequence of identity?

Comment: @Zuhair: Yes, but why does it matter that it contains the class of ordinals? That is my question. I can easily define a hierarchy that is the height of Ord: $X_0=\varnothing; X_{\alpha+1}=X_\alpha\cup\{X_\alpha\}$ and unions at limit steps. Now what? Nothing, just because something is a proper class it doesn't mean that there is some interesting theory behind it.

Comment: @AsafKaragila, Yes! I know this point. However I'm not claiming here that the interest in this theory is just that. Actually I need to know how much weak this theory is. That's why I've asked the second question. Since a positive answer to it, make this theory stronger perhaps than PA. By the way the theory of ordinals that you alluded to is very interesting if it is extended with additional axioms to let them go upwards as far as ordinals in ZF can go. Actually I think it can interpret ZF itself.