# "Theory" of a proper class model of set theory

Tags: logic, set-theory, model-theory

In the comments below [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3455955/397125), there is a question about whether "the theory" of a certain proper class is strictly weaker than Kripke-Platek. Now, if this were a set rather than a proper class, I would have immediately said, "it is a complete theory, so it can't be strictly weaker than anything (in a direct sense, anyway)". But it is a proper class, so there is no real notion of its complete theory, and I realized I don't know if there is any standard notion of the theory of a proper class. For instance, there is a reasonably natural sense in which $\mathsf{ZF+V=L}$ is "the theory of $L$": $$\mathsf{ZF}\vdash \varphi^L\iff \mathsf{ZF+V=L}\vdash \varphi.$$ On the other hand, $\mathsf{ZF+V=HOD}$ is not the theory of $HOD$ in this sense, although perhaps there is another theory that is.

So my question is whether there is some well-established idea of a theory of a proper class. Even for set-sized models, we could have a notion of the sentences that ZF(C) can prove are true or false in the model. The question is whether this is well-established and useful for anything in particular.

Comment: The way I understood the question is "what weak set theory will this class provably satisfy?", one can also ask about weaker in the sense of consistency strength. I agree that it's hard to define this "exactly".

Comment: I don't like the term "theory of a proper class" here (model theory has already laid claim to "theory of," and so in particular I'd want the theory of a proper class - like the theory of a genuine set-sized structure - to be complete). Maybe "identifier?" Incidentally, here's a precise question which might be somewhat in line with what you're asking: for a definable inner model $M$ (or really, a fixed definition of such an $M$), is there a sentence $\theta_M$ such that $$ZF\vdash\varphi^M\quad\iff\quad ZF+\theta_M\vdash\varphi?$$ As you observe, $V=M$ generally **doesn't** work for $\theta_M$.

Comment: Incidentally, for HOD we get a surprisingly simple situation: $ZFC\vdash\varphi^{HOD}$ iff $ZFC\vdash\varphi$, since every countable model of ZFC is the HOD of some other model of ZFC; see Theorem 66 of Fuchs/Hamkins/Reitz [Set-theoretic geology](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1107.4776.pdf). Since $ZF\vdash AC^{HOD}$, this tells us that $\theta_{HOD}=AC$.

Comment: @NoahSchweber I think we're on the same page about the question proper. And neat, I certainly wouldn't have expected that to be the solution for HOD. I had heard a lot of statements in HOD were independent, but hadn't heard that literally the only thing we have is that it satisfies ZFC.